# 'Plus' plattern in C prints way more columns and rows

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

If I input 3 rows and 3 columns, it prints something like this:

[image]

It should print 3 rows and 3 columns, but it prints way more than the input.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int f, c;
    printf("Rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    printf("Columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    int cruz[f][c];
    int mf=sizeof(cruz);
    int mc=sizeof(cruz[0]);
    int mitadFilas=mf/2;
    int mitadColumnas=mc/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < mf; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mc; j++) {
            if(i == mitadFilas || j == mitadColumnas) {
                cruz [i][j] =1;
            }else {
                cruz [i][j] =0;
            }
            printf("%d ",cruz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why complicate things? Why not `i < f` and `j < c` ?

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` operator is for retrieving the number of bytes in the objects, not for retrieving the number of elements in array.

In this case, you already have the number of elements as `f` and `c`, so you should use them as the number of elements.

In other words, the lines

```
    int mf=sizeof(cruz);
    int mc=sizeof(cruz[0]);
```

should be

```
    int mf=f;
    int mc=c;
```

If you want to stick to use `sizeof` for some reason, divide the size of objects by the size of one element to retrieve the number of elements.

```
    int mf=sizeof(cruz) / sizeof(cruz[0]);
    int mc=sizeof(cruz[0]) / sizeof(cruz[0][0]);
```